# How to track all requests and redirects made by iframe

Tags: javascript, debugging, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to make a debugger for web apps (something like Laravel's on-screen debug bar or Chrome devtools), and my approach is to make a webpage with an iframe that points to the target web app (independent on which technology it was developed).

When the user navigates on the embedded web app, the "main" web page needs to track all requests made by the web app (even through xhr, fetch, normal browser redirects etc), and the request data (payload, headers etc).

I'm searching some days about that and the most interesting thing I've found is a topic about Service Workers on MDN, that demonstrates how to track fetch requests and communicate between the page and the sw with message. But can't understand how I can use that.

If someone knows a method that I can build something like that, can you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, to track  network request  implement using service worker. please check go through this link https://livebook.manning.com/book/progressive-web-apps/chapter-4/5. i'll also check and let you know.

Comment: If it is in a different domain, the iframe will not be accessible because of the same origin policy. Webpage is the wrong tool for the job.